# highlight neighbor in the force layout

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I got a code snippet that can highlight neighbor nodes and make the other nodes, which are no neighbors less visible in a force layout:

```
//Toggle stores whether the highlighting is on
var toggle = 0;
//Create an array logging what is connected to what
var linkedByIndex = {};
for (i = 0; i < graph.nodes.length; i++) {
    linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
};
graph.links.forEach(function (d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});
//This function looks up whether a pair are neighbours
function neighboring(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
}
function connectedNodes() {
    if (toggle == 0) {
        //Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
        d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
        node.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
        });
        link.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1;
        });
        //Reduce the op
        toggle = 1;
    } else {
        //Put them back to opacity=1
        node.style("opacity", 1);
        link.style("opacity", 1);
        toggle = 0;
    }
}
```

My question is about these lines:

```
//Create an array logging what is connected to what
var linkedByIndex = {};
for (i = 0; i < graph.nodes.length; i++) {
    linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
```

Why is he using `{}` for creating an array and not `[]`?
Also what is this means:

```
linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1
```

is that "1" something similiar to "true"?

The same goes for this line

```
graph.links.forEach(function (d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
```

I mean, it checks, if the source and the target are the same (connection between nodes), but I do not understand that syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blockquote
>   Why is he using {} for creating an array and not []? Also what is this means: linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1

It's not an array, it's a js object, see this [link for more info](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)
The second line is assigning the property name of `linkedByIndex` to `1`

> Blockquote
>   is that "1" something similiar to "true"?

Kind of, `1` means the link is present, `undefined` means it's not. `neighboring(d, o)` will be `true` if `linkedByIndex[d + "," + o] === 1`

Comment: Thanks my friend for the help! You said, that the second line is assigning the property name of linkedByIndex to 1. But it goes through a loop. Let's say the lenght is five. So this line creats

Comment: creates or assign 5 times the property name of linkedByIndex to 1? But for what exactly`?

Comment: @HansiSchmidt linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1 means that each node is his own neighbour. It assigns linkedByIndex["0,0"] to 1, then linkedByIndex["1,1"] to 1 etc .... Basically linkedByIndex a [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix)

Comment: Then it will become [an adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)

Comment: Hey Tim! Thanks again

Comment: Now, i got one idendity matrix looks like this

Comment: 1 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 0 0

0 0 1 0 0

0 0 0 1 0

0 0 0 0 1

Comment: oh damit, cannot copy and paste a matrix here

Comment: my question was, the code created 1 idendiy matrix and an adjacency matrix, so i got 2 matrix. but what is this code doing with the matrix? function neighboring(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
}

Comment: The matrix gives information about the links : if A is linked to B, then linkedByIndex(A + "," + B) === 1, otherwise its null

Comment: thanks Tim! But where do you got the information from, that linkedByIndex(A + "," + B) will return a true or false (1 or 0)? How do you know it?

Comment: linkedByIndex = {} means the object is empty, then you set the value for each link (linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;)